# Why my squared numbers won't get printed?

Tags: python, function, exponent

```
def square(x):
    x = 2**x

    x = 2.0
    while x < 100.0:
    print x, '\t', square(x)
    x = square(x)
```

I tried to print. But it won't print. What I actually wanted were the squares of 2. But it won't be printing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `x = 2.0` is just going to reset x back to `2.0` each time you run the function. so you do `x = 2^x` and throw away that value.

Comment: You have infinite recursion -- you're calling `square(x)` inside the definition of `square(x)`.

Comment: You are making it an infinite recurrsion just return the value

Comment: Remember that Python cares very much about indentation. All the statements starting with `x = 2.0` are part of the function definition, because they're indented.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation first? are `x = 2.0` and `while ...` actually unindented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even make it look like

```
while i<100.0:
   print x**2,"\t"
   i+=1#If you increment i by one
```

The mistake you made is **not returning** the value
Add a statement **return sqvalue** where sqvalue is the squared of the value you give as input.

```
def square(int x):
   sqvalue=x**2
   return sqvalue
```

or write it in a single line function

```
def square(int x):
   return x**2
```

I suggest you may take a look at lambda(anonymous functions) for these simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

you should return a value.

```
def square(x):
    y = 2**x
    return y
```

and increment x value.

```
while x < 100.0:
     print x, '\t', square(x)
     x += increment_value
```

I think `square(x) = x^2 not 2^x` ?